# iMessages sending to old phone

Tags: iphone

I gave my old iphone 3 to my friend and have realised he is receiving my imessages that i receive on my new iphone 4S. Please can you tell me how i stop this so he stops received my messages?

thanks

Caroline

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this on the iPhone 3:

1. Go to **Settings / Messages / Receive at...**
2. Tap on your Apple ID and Log Out.

Answer (score 1):

You should have reset your phone before passing it to someone else. I'd suggest asking your friend to reset your phone by going to:

**Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings**

This will erase all your personal content and settings from the device.